# Does JMeter support TLS v1.1 or TLS v1.2

Tags: java, ssl, jmeter, tls1.2

I searched the official JMeter docs and found that it does support TLS in general, but I am not able to find any specific data regarding TLS versions 1.1 or 1.2.

Can anyone provide a definitive answer?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I haven't tried it out yet but looks like if I'm using Java 7 I can pass in: https.socket.protocols=SSLv2Hello SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
Does this look right?

Comment: Yes, but NEVER your SSLv2Hello and burry SSLv3 immediately.

Answer (score 5):

This is not upto JMeter but the JSSE implemenation in the JVM. [TLS 1.1 and 1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) are supported in Java 7 only.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your Java version as @Michael-O stated, but JMeter support [TLS](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html):

> JMeter HTTP defaults to protocol level TLS. This can be changed by
>   editing the JMeter property `https.default.protocol` in
>   jmeter.properties or user.properties.

JMeter takes the value and use it in `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(String protocol)` so it boils down to Java support.